# How to dynamically change text of empty view in listfragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment, empty-list

I have red many solutions regarding this but none of them solved my problem.
What i want to do is, when my list view is empty its ok if the default empty text view shows up (which is declared in xml) but what if i want to change its text at some point in an activity that extends listfragment according to my need and make it visible....
Recently i tried this:

```
public void setEmptyText(CharSequence emptyText) {
    ListView mListView = (ListView) NotificationsView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    View emptyView = mListView.getEmptyView();
        ((TextView) emptyView).setText(emptyText);
}
```

It doesn't give any error but it is not solving the problem too. Any Help would be appreciated thanks

**EDIT:**
here is my layout of listfragment

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/fragment_bg"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_style" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/fragment_bg"
            android:text="No data" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your layout where you are declaring your text view and list view.. It doesn't make sense to casting a view into a text view and then assigning a text to it.. The problem in hand is not very clear.. Please elaborate..

Comment: You dont have to see my previous code as i knw there was something wrong with it thats why it was not working. I just need to change the text by some way.

Comment: Added the answer.. You were not referencing the text view properly.. You don't need to fetch a view , cast it to text view and then set it.. The reason you were not getting any error was because view is the parent of textview..

Comment: One second.. Are you treating the text view in your layout as the item in your list view? If yes, then I am afraid now that you have got the whole logic wrong.. This is not the way to implement the list.. This way you are declaring a list and a text view just below it.. Since the list doesn't have any items, it's always empty and doesn't show up on screen.. Rather all you can see (after changing the value of the text view), is the updated text in the text view..

Comment: What did you add in the answer? i cant see any changes... and i have changed my layout code.

Comment: It is not what you are thinking it is..... The textview is actually an empty view which is used with lists. when the list is empty the empty view shows up with some text. Its a default android behaviour. The way i have referenced the text view and list in layout now is not incorrect

Comment: I have added the answer as answer, not as a comment.. I have posted the exact way to change the text view's value.. And its strange if you can't find the difference.. :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ListFragment` all you need to do is call the method

```
setEmptyText("Your empty text"):
```

The system will recognize the view label with the `android:id="@id/android:empty"` id and will change the text for you. No need to reference it or do any cast, it's all built in the `ListFragment`

Comment: yea it is also right.. all i was doing wrong was that i was calling it at wrong place..... I had to call it when the activity gets created in listfragment.

Answer (score 0):

By default the listview or adapter (don't remember which one) makes it invisible. Call `emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` to make it visible.

Comment: He is asking about changing the value of text view, not making the list visible or not visible..

Comment: can i change the text of the emptyview with setEmptytext() ? if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to change the value of a text view:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
tv.setText('yourText');
```

Comment: You can't refrence to an empty View like you refrence to anyother textView.... I have tried it

Comment: Turns out i was doing it right before.... I was just doing a silly mistake..... The textView and listView were in SwipeRefreshLayout and it was only showing listview not the textView. when i enclose listview and textview in linearlayout. now if the list is empty the emptyview shows up and if the listview has some items the emptyview gets hidden (which is default android behaviour).... and i can change the text of emptyview anytime by the same method in my question.. Btw thanx For your help buddy :) ... I am thankful to you

Comment: I think it is obvious that OP knows how to set a text on a `TextView`, you can see it in his code